# Controlling the line-height of a <br> tag within a heading tag?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have a heading (`<h1>`) that has a sort of tagline below it. (I used a `<small>` tag and set `font-size` to a certain percent so it lines up perfectly when I change `font-size` of the heading for smaller screens. I'm using `em` units, if that matters.)

At first, the `<small>` tag sat nicely underneath the main heading, but I realized I forgot the HTML5 DOCTYPE declaration. So, after I discovered this omission and corrected it, the spacing was all wrong.

**Here's my code:**

HTML:

```html
<h1 class="banner">Justin Wilson<br /><small>WEB + GRAPHIC DESIGNER</small></h1>
```

CSS:

```css
h1.banner {
text-align: center;
display: block;
font-family: 'arvil';
font-size: 6.5em;
color: #94babd; }

h1.banner > small {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 27%;
color: #888;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 100; }
```

**And here's the before and after:**

[image: Before and after doctype declaration]

I have searched through StackOverflow, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I've read that a `<br />` tag simply line breaks, but it inherits the line-spacing, and `line-spacing: (value)` does not work, nor do margins or padding.

What I need is a simple, cross-browser solution. I used Chrome for the screenshot. Support for IE6-7 is not needed, though support for IE8 would be nice.

Comment: Why not using <h2> or others for the 2nd row?

Comment: Well, it's part of the main heading, my name and title. The title is the "tagline" in a way.

Comment: @JEES - [The HTML5 spec specifically says not to do that.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, @Alohci, hence the `<small>` tag.

Comment: I also want to note that there are "solutions" that involve changing the `<br />` tag's CSS, but as @Robbert mentioned, it isn't advised. A lot of varied results when I tried this: `h1 > br {content: " "; display: block; margin: -.5em;}`

Comment: @JustinW - One of the HTML5 editors, Steve Faulkner also says [here](http://html5doctor.com/howto-subheadings/) "Note: Some have been advocating of the use of the small element to signify subtitles. This has been under discussion in the HTML working group, but no compelling arguments for its use have been made. Therefore it is not advised to use small to mark up subtitles." However, that is not yet W3C policy in any way, and personally I rather approve of using `small` in that way.

Comment: @alohci You're right but i didn't mean `<h2>` particularly  this why i said or others, just meant not including HTML markup inside `<h1>`.. anyways the semantic way is using header groups `<hgroup>` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hgroup.html , also http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/

Comment: @JEES - hgroup is now obsolete in HTML5.

Comment: @Alohci, you have a link? [html5semantic] updated April,3 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)

Comment: There's this (which is unfortunate, seeing as hgroup seems like a good solution): [http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-hgroup-element-dropped/](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-hgroup-element-dropped/)

Comment: @JustinW thanks for the link, @ Aohci, many thanks for telling about dropping hgroups +1

Comment: If we are really gonna discuss which elements Justin should use I think we should drop the `<h1>` altogether when we look at this case from an SEO perspective. The heading tags (`<h1>` through `<h7>`) should only be used for the actual page's content. The page title should be in `<h1>`, any subchapter in `<h2>`, et cetera. Justin would probably be best of using an `<a>` tag set to `display:block;` for his logo, which would then link to the home page. Either a `<span>` (also set to `display:block;`) or `<div>` could then be used for the subtitle. The latter saves both HTML and CSS file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the answer that works as the best solution is found here (3rd example):

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head

@cimmanon posted a very helpful solution, but to be safe, I'll stick with what Steve Faulkner said about this being a more semantic and SEO-friendly solution over using an `<h1>` tag and `<h2>` tag for a subheading, or inline elements inside a heading tag, regardless of styling.

**Here's the solution:**

HTML:

```
  <header>
    <h1 class="banner">Justin Wilson</h1>
    <p>WEB + GRAPHIC DESIGNER</p>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
  h1.banner {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'arvil';
  font-size: 6.5em;
  color: #94babd;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;/*purely for display purposes, really*/ }

  header > p {font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  color: #888;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;  }
```

And the live demo (might not look good to you without the free Arvil font, from Lost Fonts).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/xysgkffs

Thanks for all the answers thus far.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the default line height for the heading element. The default depends on the browser and on the font, but it tends to be about 1.1 to 1.3 times the font size. In any case, with a very large font size set, this creates a problem, because the line height value also sets the height of the second line. By CSS specifications, for a block element, [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) sets the *minimum* height of line boxes.

There are various ways around this. Setting `display: block` on the `small` element is one way, since then its default line height will be determined according to its own font size. Another way is to set a line height that is considerably smaller than the font size, e.g.

```
h1.banner { line-height: 0.5; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to control the `line-height` css property (see [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)) to make sure all browsers set the same height for each line.

It's actually advisable to do this to pretty much all elements containing text, which is why most people use CSS resets for production, which sets a default line-height across all elements.

In this case, the `<span>` and `<h1>` will likely have different line heights.

I'm sure the `<br />` tag is doing nothing wrong, unless you've altered its properties with CSS which I would not advise.

There's also a shorthand version in case you're setting other font properties for the same element(s):

```
font: <font weight> <font size>/<line height> <font face>;
```

For example:

```
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using Normalize, but I guess there isn't anything that declares a default line-height. Any suggestion on a more thorough reset? I suppose I can just add some in..

Comment: The CSS reset discussion has been around for years. I can't provide you with a simple solution here that would not spark a big discussion on CSS resets. You can check out [cssreset.com](http://www.cssreset.com/) for current popular CSS reset methods. As you use CSS more you will likely end up using your own CSS reset based on your needs and style anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `<br />` and set the display of the `<small>` element to block.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/uoqfo4xw

```
<h1 class="banner">Justin Wilson <small>WEB + GRAPHIC DESIGNER</small></h1>

h1.banner {
text-align: center;
display: block;
font-family: 'arvil';
font-size: 6.5em;
color: #94babd; }

h1.banner > small {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 27%;
color: #888;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 100;
display: block; }
```

Comment: Excellent. This does work, as does using a `<header>` tag, with a heading and paragraph tag (containing the tagline).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to set the span to `display: block;` and then adjust the `line-height` of the `<h2>` tag.

I would do this, instead of using a `<br />` tag.

Comment: True, but then there's no need in using a `<span>` either. Justin could just use a block element instead, like a `<div>` or an `<h2>` as suggested. Though I'd prefer using a `<div>` because an `<h2>` would signify a sub-chapter, which it is not.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED....**

Change `<small>` to `<p>` in HTML and CSS and add line to the `h1.banner > p`

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7WMda/2/)

Comment: If you widen the view on that fiddle, or any screen, the tagline doesn't line up. It sticks to an absolute position, relative to the viewport.

Comment: Didn't say it's the good way, I wouldn't do it this way if it was me

Comment: So... why did you suggest doing it this way, then..?

Comment: I didn't suggested actually, I typed "if you are still convinced to use it your way"

Comment: That's one way of doing it, yes. But... here's a related question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379739/p-tag-in-h1-for-seo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379739/p-tag-in-h1-for-seo). Steve Faulkner suggests using a `<header>` tag (3rd example): [http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head). This might be my solution, actually.

Comment: @JustinW, happy for you :) , Although i think @cimmanon's answer is better, dropping the `<br>` I mean.

Comment: Actually I already know it's invalid even in xhtml I just forgot about it, But I'm happy I've learned that `<hgroup>` is dropped now thanks to @Alohci