# Is it valid to have paragraph elements inside of a heading tag in HTML5 (P inside H1)?

Tags: css, html, w3c

Is it OK to have paragraph elements inside of a header tags in HTML5?

In other words: is this markup correct in HTML5? What are the drawbacks of using this?

```
<h1>
    <p class="major">Major part</p>
    <p class="minor">Minor part</p>
</h1>
```

If not, how can I style these elements with CSS correctly?

Comment: @user2864740 Though he did provide a good answer, he should have posted it on the **[original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379739/p-tag-in-h1-for-seo)**. He knew it existed, **[as he just made a suggested edit on one of its answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14666435/revisions)**

Comment: I just wanted to address this issue in a more broader sense as i often see this in practice and i couldn't find an appropriate answer with Google or SA. I think it can save some time to less experienced developers.

The so-called "original" question is just too narrow for my extended answer. Again, my question has a broader meaning.

Comment: Common sense would tell you that it's not, and as far as I'm aware, this is not one of the areas where HTML flagrantly violates common sense, even though [it does define "paragraph" slightly differently from common usage of the word](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element). (I realize this is self-answered; my comment is directed not at you but at anyone who happens to be asking themself the same question, and is meant to encourage them to just think about it for a moment.)

Comment: react screamed once at me when i used a div inside a p, since then i've learned my lesson so i assume is not ideal for SEO as well

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Actually, no. This markup is not correct according to W3C. You should avoid using this.

[It is stated](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) that the correct content for header elements is a "*phrasing content*", which is *[phrasing elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content) intermixed with normal character data*.

In other words you can use the following convenient elements inside of a header tag in HTML5: **a, em, strong, code, cite, span, br, img**. [See the full list here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content).

[The W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) will give you the following error if you will try to validate this markup: **Element p not allowed as child of element h1 in this context.**

The one major drawback of using this markup that you should consider is that *[search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_search_engine)* can incorrectly parse your heading tag and miss important data. So this practice can be bad for [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

If you would like a better SEO results it is a good practice to include only textual data inside of a heading elements. But, if you also need to apply some styles, you can use the following markup and CSS:

```
<h1>
    <span class="major">Major part</span>
    <span class="minor">Minor part</span>
</h1>

<style type="text/css">
    h1 span {
        display: block;
    }
    h1 span.major {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    h1 span.minor {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
```

See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8FFG/) for this.

As stated before, **span** tag is perfectly valid inside of a header elements (h1-h6). And you can apply "**display: block;**" style to it to make it render as a block level element (each on a different line). It will save you a **br** tag.

Of course you will need to change this CSS selectors according to your use case.

And yes, as [stUrb said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid#comment29400245_19779520) it's not semantically correct to use paragraphs inside of a headings. The most important idea behind HTML is that it must be a **semantics first, presentation later**.

Comment: Clear explanation! Its also semantic not correct: Having a paragraph within a heading.

Comment: is a **b** tab valid inside a heading tag? Would that have any negative implications on SEO?

Comment: Are you talking about `<b>` element? If so, you should avoid using it in the first place, because it's a representational element and HTML should be used for information structure and semantics. CSS should handle presentation layer on top of that.

Comment: @snow: b isn't purely presentational in HTML5, but there is almost never a situation in which you would find yourself using b in a heading.