# Centering a heading inside a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to center a heading `h1` inside of a `div` with `.box` class when the browser window width is less than 768 px.

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 250px 0 0 0;
  height: 35%;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url('img/header-bcg.png');
}
.box h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Bree serif;
  color: 33adae;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  line-height: 10px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  footer,
  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1><p>Moderní webdesign</p> za nejnižší ceny!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not have `p` inside `h1`

Comment: Working perfectly, feel free to make an answer. @GermanoPlebani

Comment: Add `float: none;` to `.box h1` in media query

Comment: Also a working solution. @NenadVracar

Comment: Use `span` instead of `p` inside `h1`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid

Answer (score 1):

Amongs other solutions, you can make your div to be rendered as a Table, and the h1 as a table-cell.

You also need to the body of the documento to be 100% of the window height, if you dont, it'll be the height of its content.

So, for the solution, it would be something like:

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
  .box {
    display:table;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        text-align: center;
  }
    .box h1 {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/QjRjwv)

Links

- [Vertical Align - W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)
- [Vertical Align - CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)
- [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide - CSSTricks (great article)](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: This answer provides useful links

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-cell;` for centering `h1` vertically and horizontally.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5pz0x51/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 250px 0 0 0;
  height: 35%;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url('img/header-bcg.png');
}
.box h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Bree serif;
  color: 33adae;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  line-height: 10px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .box h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  footer,
  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1><p>Moderní webdesign</p> za nejnižší ceny!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

H1 floated it's large as much as letters contained. Adding width 100% align can works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a HTML error. `<p>` it´s not not allowed inside a heading.

Said that, you should use a `<span>` instead. Then you can center normally with `text-align`

**CSS**

```
 .box h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nft4oeab/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between inline elements and block elements in HTML.

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available, when an inline element does not start on a new
>   line and only takes up as much width as necessary.

Examples of inline elements in HTML:

```
<span></span>
<a href='#'></a>
<img src='#'></img>
```

Block elements:

```
<div>
<h1> - <h6>
<p>
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily centre the heading bootstrap 4.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="mx-auto">Centered Heading</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```