# Putting an <H2> with my text <p> while having it styled with "text-align:center;" don't work

Tags: html, css, text-styling

This is for a drop down menu of 4 columns.

On the first column with is the "HOME" within a div, I have the text "HOME" in a

tag.

ex. `<p style="text-align:center;"> HOME </p>`

now if I try an add in `<H2> </H2>`  between HOME, it cancels out the text-align:center and just uses the H2.

What so I need to do in the css to keep both the style="text-align:center and H2 in the same

tag?....if possible anyway, because I like to keep the text-align:center with H2 on the text in the same paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
<h2>
<p style="text-align:center;">HOME </p>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: why do you need a paragraph inside a heading element?

Heading elements are meant to highlight important parts of your site, i.e. `headings`, and are also indexed by search engines. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp. While paragraphs are larger trunks of text, and will add some space before and after the `paragraph` (since it's a block element) read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp.

To answer your question:

Semantically it is not correct to a paragraph inside a heading or reversed: i.e.

```
<!-- INCORRECT -->
<h2>
  <p>Your heading</p>
</h2>
```

What you should do is style the heading element directly:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<h2>Your heading</h2>

/** CSS **/
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I also realized something similar has been answered before: [Is it valid to have paragraph elements inside of a heading tag in HTML5 (P inside H1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid)

Just a little side thought: you mention having a drop-down of 4 columns. Wouldn't an `<h2>` element be too big to have in a drop-down? I immediately was thinking that it would be better having a bold font instead to highlight that specific element. But notice that I do not have any knowledge of your project! :P

Answer (score 0):

you may try this instead of inline css code.. try to use tag

`<h2><center>HOME</center></h2>`