# Behavior of the scrapy xpath selector on h1-h6 tags

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, selector

Why does the following two code snippets give different outputs?  The only difference between them is that the `h1` tag in the first case is replaced with an `h` tag in the second case.  Is this because the `h1` tag has a special "meaning" in html?  I tried with `h1` through `h6` and all of them give `[]` as output, while with `h7` it starts to give `[u'xxx']` as output.

```
from scrapy import Selector # scrapy version: 1.2.2

text = '<h1><p>xxx</p></h1>'
print Selector(text=text).xpath('//h1/p/text()').extract()
Output[1]: []

text = '<h><p>xxx</p></h>'
print Selector(text=text).xpath('//h/p/text()').extract()
Output[2]: [u'xxx']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including `p` tags inside `h#` is invalid according to W3C. You can see more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid)

Anyway, to bypass this and just work with any `xml` structure you can just change the `type` like this:

```
sel = Selector(text="anyxml", type="xml")
```

This will respect any xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that `h1`..`h6` should not contain `<p>` in well-formed HTML documents, at least lxml (which powers Scrapy Selectors) does not like that when parsing HTML. lxml does handle bad formatting, but this case it a bit different.

You can check how lxml parses and serializes back the HTML snippet:

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> text = '<h1><p>xxx</p></h1>'
>>> s = Selector(text=text)
>>> print(s.extract())
<html><body><h1></h1><p>xxx</p></body></html>
```

So when lxml encounters the `p` tag within the `h1`, it puts it after it. The `p` element is not lost, but it's not where you'd expect it when reading the HTML source.

vs the other snippet:

```
>>> text = '<h><p>xxx</p></h>'
>>> s = Selector(text=text)
>>> print(s.extract())
<html><body><h><p>xxx</p></h></body></html>
>>>
```

`h` elements do not mean anything special for lxml, so "`p` within `h`" is *ok*.

Comment: Thanks for showing that print(s.extract()) tells what is under the hood!