# What's the correct Scrapy XPath for <p> elements incorrectly placed within <h> tags?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am setting up my first Scrapy Spider, and I'm having some difficulty using xpath to extract certain elements.

My target is http://www.cbooo.cn/m/641515  (a Chinese website similar to Box Office Mojo). I can extract the Chinese name of the film 阿龙浴血记 with no problem , but I can't figure out how to get the information below it. I believe this is because the HTML is not standard, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356281/extracting-p-within-h1-with-python-scrapy). There are several paragraph elements nested beneath the  header.

I have tried the solution in the link above, and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063971/behavior-of-the-scrapy-xpath-selector-on-h1-h6-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1), to no avail.

```
def parse(self, response):
    chinesetitle = response.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/text()').extract()
    englishtitle = response.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/p').extract()
    chinesereleasedate = response.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[4]').extract()
    productionregions = response.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[6]').extract()
    chineseboxoffice = response.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/span/text()[2]').extract()
    yield {
        'chinesetitle': chinesetitle,
        'englishtitle': englishtitle,
        'chinesereleasedate': chinesereleasedate,
        'productionregions': productionregions,
        'chineseboxoffice': chineseboxoffice
        }
```

When I run the spider in the Scrapy shell, the spider finds the Chinese title as expected. However, the remaining items return either a [], or a weird mish-mash of text on the page.

Any advice? This is my first amature programming project, so I appreciate your patience with my ignorance and your help. Thank you!

**EDIT**

Tried implement the text cleaning method in the comments. The example in the comments worked, but when I tried to reimplement it I got an "Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'“ (please see the China Box Office, country of origin, and genre examples below)

```
def parse(self, response):
        chinesetitle = response.css('.cont h2::text').extract_first()
        englishtitle = response.css('.cont h2 + p::text').extract_first()
        chinaboxoffice = response.xpath('//span[@class="m-span"]/text()[2]').extract_first()        
        chinaboxoffice = chinaboxoffice.split('万')[0]
        chinareleasedate = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p[contains(text(),"上映时间")]/text()').extract_first()
        chinareleasedate = chinareleasedate.split('：')[1].split('（')[0]
        countryoforigin = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p')[6].xpath('text()').extract_first()
        countryoforigin = countryoforigin.split('：')[1]
        genre = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p[contains(text(),"类型")]/text()').extract_first()
        genre = genre.split('：')[1]
        director = response.xpath('//*[@id="tabcont1"]/dl/dd[1]/p/a/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Those are actually allowed in html5, scrapy just doesn't support it and probably never will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples from which you can infer the last one. Remember to always use a class or id attribute to identify the html element. `/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/..` is not a good practise.

```
chinesetitle = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/h2/text()').extract_first()
englishtitle = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p/text()').extract_first()
chinesereleasedate = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p[contains(text(),"上映时间")]/text()').extract_first())
productionregions = response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p')[6].xpath('text()').extract_first()
```

To find `chinesereleasedate` I took the `p` element whose text contains `'上映时间'`. You have to parse this to get the exact value.

To find `productionregions` I took the 7th selector from the list `response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p')[6]` selected the text. A better method would be to check if the text contains '国家及地区' just like above.

**Edit :** To answer the question in the comments,

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="ziliaofr"]/div/p[contains(text(),"上映时间")]/text()').extract_first()
```

returns a string like `'\r\n                        上映时间：2017-7-27（中国）\r\n                 '` which is not what you are looking for. You can clean it up like:

`chinesereleasedate = chinesereleasedate.split('：')[1].split('（')[0]`

This gives us the correct date.

Comment: Understood your point about the class attribute, very useful information. When you say "You have to parse this to get the exact value", what do you mean?

Comment: Parsing was not the right word. Added it to the answer. Please accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now see what you mean. Your method worked for me. I tried to redo it for other fields, but I now get an error stating "Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". I've edited my original post, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to torture yourself with xpath by the way, you can use css:

```
response.css('.cont h2::text').extract_first()
# '战狼2'
response.css('.cont h2 + p::text').extract_first()
# 'Wolf Warriors 2'
```