# Stop php DomDocument / LibXML restructing content

Tags: php, html, domdocument

When loading HTML content with DomDocument it gets restructured.

I know that **p** tags are not allowed inside **h1** but this is what I have to work with. Whilst the spec says it’s not allowed everything is still correctly nested (no missing closing tag etc.)

```
...
<h1>
    <p>Nested paragraph</p>
</h1>
...
```

Then when run

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

It will output like so

```
<h1>

</h1>
<p>Nested paragraph</p>
```

The **p** has been moved outside the **h1**. Is there a way to tell it not to care about matching the spec but just ensure tags are closed etc. How’s this going to work with custom elements in the future?

Comment: Probably because according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid it's not valid.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, I know this is not valid but that’s how I receive the HTML. I’m asking if I can stop DomDocument from editing this HTML.

Comment: If you treat it as XML - then it's OK, but this of course may cause other issues.

Comment: You could pre-process the source HTML prior to using DOMDocument, and the re-set it after you've exported it.