# xpath <p> inside <h3> empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I started to work with xpath in python3 and are facing this behaviour. It seems very wrong to me. Why does it match span-text, but not p-text inside h3?

```
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> result = "<h3><p>Hallo</p></h3>"
>>> tree = etree.HTML(result)
>>> r = tree.xpath('//h3//text()')
>>> print(r)
[]

>>> result = "<h3><span>Hallo</span></h3>"
>>> tree = etree.HTML(result)
>>> r = tree.xpath('//h3//text()')
>>> print(r)
['Hallo']
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first XPath correctly returned no result because `<h3>` in the corresponding `tree` didn't contain any text node. You can use `tostring()` method to see the actual content of the tree :

```
>>> result = "<h3><p>Hallo</p></h3>"
>>> tree = etree.HTML(result)
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<html><body><h3/><p>Hallo</p></body></html>'
```

The parser *probably* did this -turned `h3` into empty element- because it considers paragraph inside a heading tag not valid (while span inside heading is valid) : [Is it valid to have paragraph elements inside of a heading tag in HTML5 (P inside H1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid)

To keep `p` elements inside `h3` you can try using different parser i.e using [BeautifulSoup's parser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) :

```
>>> from lxml.html import soupparser
>>> result = "<h3><p>Hallo</p></h3>"
>>> tree = soupparser.fromstring(result)
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<html><h3><p>Hallo</p></h3></html>'
```

Comment: Is there any way to work around this problem? I'm scraping websites and many websites use this syntax. Can I somehow change the way it reads the html?
Beside: I'm able to put div-Elements inside h3, althought div is als not a "Phrasing content"-Element.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!