# DOMDocument moves <p> tags outside of <h1> tags - what now?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

According to this summary of the HTML standards, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779520/2113148, `<p><p/>` shall not be part of headings.

In PHP, this is translated to the following DOMDocument behaviour:

```php
$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$html = "<html><body><h1><p>Hello</p></h1></body></html>";

@$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$output = $DOM->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
"""
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><h1></h1><p>Hello</p></body></html>
"""
```

The paragraph tag is moved outside of the heading tag.

But this is not very "user-friendly" as websites don't stick to the rules and one can very simply understand what is meant by original HTML.

How can one disable or hot-wire this behaviour and make DOMDocument behave graciously?

Browsers don't parse it like DOMDocument and we also understand it differently.

Comment: Try it in a browser, it may do the same thing.

Comment: I doesn't. Browsers parse it differently. Check for example the h1 on https://midesk.co

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, if your html is also well formed xml, you can parse it as xml:

```
$DOM->loadXML($html);
$output = $DOM->saveXML($DOM->documentElement);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
<html><body><h1><p>Hello</p></h1></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I will research it.